# Observable editor functionality

Tags: observablehq

I'm new to Observable and as I was editing a notebook I selected several lines and then used the Command-/ keystroke and it "//" commented all the selected lines. I use this command frequently in VS Code and used it in Observable by reflex. I was surprised it worked.

Is there is list of the functions the Observable editor implements? Is there a manual available for the editor it uses for editing cells?

Answer (score 1):

There's a comprehensive list of editor shortcuts that you can access by clicking the ? icon in the bottom right of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can also type **?** to toggle the keyboard tab.

More info on keyboard shortcuts here https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/keyboard-shortcuts

[image: Keyboard shortcuts button]